# I can't convert an unknown column in to a date column and then change format to dd-mm-yyyy

Tags: r

I know it seems that this may be a repeated question, but I have tried other solutions and still cannot get it to work. I have uploaded a .csv file into r. I have done a small amount of house cleaning but ultimately I would like to convert a column from '"POSIXct" "POSIXt"' to a 'date' column type, and a 'character' column to a 'numeric'. For the latter column (change) I have decimals and --- entries, I converted the --- to NA, but fail to convert it to a 'numeric' afterwards.

```
df$value <- as.numeric(as.character(df$value))
```

I first used:

```
df$date <- dmy_hm(df$time_stamp, tz = "Europe/London")
```

to create a new date variable / column. But this did not give 'date' as a column type. I then tried using:

```
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
```

but this did not work. Once I have converted to 'date' I need to convert the format from `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` to `dd/mm/yyyy`.

Any help with will greatly received.

Comment: please paste the output of `dput(df)` of your dataframe and the expected output `df`

Comment: There is no such thing as an "unknown column type" in R.

Comment: Sorry yes you are right when I viewed the column types in table view I got 'unknown' having run sapply(df, class) the column type is "POSIXct" "POSIXt" .

Answer (score 0):

lubridate package can be wacky sometimes. Can you share head of you .csv data? you might have confused with dmy_hms with myd_hms or ymd_hms  formats. Try using [anytime package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anytime/anytime.pdf).

```
anytime::anytime(df$time_stamp)
```